# Merging two sorted linked lists in Python

Tags: python, sorting, merge, linked-list

I am solving a Leetcode question (Problem #21) that takes two sorted linked lists and returns a sorted, merged linked list. For example, Input: 1->2->4, 1->3->4 and Output: 1->1->2->3->4->4.

I am not super experienced with linked lists, but am trying to tackle more problems to gain exposure. Instead of returning the desired output, of [1,1,2,3,4,4], my code just returns [4]. However, I think the main logic is there, and I am hopefully missing something small.

```
def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        newList = ListNode(0) # used for single, merged list
        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val <= l2.val: # compare current node's values
                newList.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                newList.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next

        return newList.next # first node is 0, which we don't want
```

Comment: There are two basic variations of this. One is to merge both lists into an empty list, the other is to merge one of the lists into the other list, which may be a bit faster, since some of the time, only a reference to the list being merged into needs to be advanced as opposed to having to set linkages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main logic is almost there but you are only replacing the next item in the list each time (you did not advance the list), thus you are only returning the last item. Solution is to create another 'cur pointer' for advancing the list while keeping newList as the 'front pointer' for returning the result.

Also at the end, you should 'concat' with the non-empty list

```
def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
    newList = ListNode(0)
    cur = newList 
    while l1 and l2:
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            cur.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next
        else:
            cur.next = l2
            l2 = l2.next
        cur = cur.next
    cur.next = l1 or l2 # add non-empty list
    return newList.next
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and pointing out the issues in my code! I get the point about advancing the current pointer with cur = cur.next. However, I have two follow-up questions: 1) What does the cur.next = l1 or l2 do? and 2) What does the cur = newList do/ how is newList.next able to return the correct result?

Comment: @JaneSully 1) the while loop terminates when one list is empty, `l1 or l2` gives us the non-empty list if there is one. if can be written as: `if l1: cur.next = l1 else: cur.next = l2`

Comment: @JaneSully 2) `cur = newList` gives us a reference to the new node (Note that this is not making a new actual copy, but only a reference), thus we can use cur to advance the linkedlist, while newList will still be a reference to the Node with value 0, returning newList.next gives us the first item appended if any.

Comment: Thanks for your super helpful clarifications! One quick follow-up: since cur references the new node with cur = newList, don't we want to advance newList instead of cur (does it matter even)?  Thanks again!

Comment: @JaneSully It is fine to swap all cur with newList in the code, it will still work. You need to have one that is pointing to the start of the List (this you do not advance) for returning the result.